# Express JS handle response if param Id is empty

Tags: node.js, express

I've a API built with **Express JS** to find a data, with **GET** method. Successfully get the data.
Here is my code:

#### Route.js

```
router.get('/personal/:id', cont.personal.getPersonalDataById)
```

#### Controller.js

```
getPersonalDataById: function (req, res) {
    PersonalInfo.findOne({
        where: { id: req.params.id }
    }).then(result => {
        if(result){
            utils.success(res, result)
        } else {
            utils.fail(res, 'Personal Data Not Found')
        }
    }).catch(reason => utils.fail(res, reason))
}
```

My issue is it will get all of data if I do request `localhost:3000/personal/` I mean request without param, how do I can send response **ID Param can't be empty** if the request has no param? Can I do it with catch or anything else? or should only work with manual validation like:

```
var id = req.params.id;
if(id == null){
    utils.fail(res, "ID Param can't be empty");
}

//OR

if(!id){
    utils.fail(res, "ID Param can't be empty");
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: Id `next()` to the error handling middleware. i.e search `sub-stack` [on this page](https://expressjs.com/tr/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: I didn't got it. Can more explain?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `express-validation` and `joi`.

you'r route should looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const validate = require('express-validation');
const Joi = require('joi');

const routeValidation = {
    // GET /personal/:id
  personal: {
    params: {
      userId: Joi.string().required(),
    },
  },
}

router.get('/personal/:id', validate(listUsers), cont.personal.getPersonalDataById)
```

Thanksfull this, you will do validations befor you do some operatios on server

Comment: I did it, I mean I'm using express-validation. But I did it in controller. Is there anygood reason why I shoul move my validation into route? Because I think it will take thousand of line code if I have more than 50 routing define in index.js